# Why is one ffmpeg webm dash stream much larger than the others?

Tags: ffmpeg, webm, mpeg-dash

Over the summer, I worked on putting together a script which took a x264 video/mp3 stream and broke it up into the different streams so that it would work via MSE-DASH. (Based heavily on the instructions on the [webmproject.org website](http://wiki.webmproject.org/adaptive-streaming/instructions-to-playback-adaptive-webm-using-dash)) Those same scripts have ceased to work, turning a 6GB video into several 25 Gb videos. I kept up with updates of ffmpeg and so I don't know when it stopped working, but I am guessing it was due to the way that their DASH Webm implementation was updated.

I found new method which works better, but still has a major problem with one stream. I was hoping someone could explain how this encoding works so that I could understand the underlying cause.

```
#!/bin/bash
COMMON_OPTS="-map 0:0 -an -threads 11 -cpu-used 4 -cmp chroma"
WEBM_OPTS="-f webm -c:v vp9 -keyint_min 50 -g 50 -dash 1"

ffmpeg -i $1 -vn -acodec libvorbis -ab 128k audio.webm &
ffmpeg -i $1 $COMMON_OPTS $WEBM_OPTS -b:v 500k -vf scale=1280:720 -y vid-500k.webm &
ffmpeg -i $1 $COMMON_OPTS $WEBM_OPTS -b:v 700k -vf scale=1280:720 -y vid-700k.webm & 
ffmpeg -i $1 $COMMON_OPTS $WEBM_OPTS -b:v 1000k -vf scale=1280:720 -y vid-1000k.webm &
ffmpeg -i $1 $COMMON_OPTS $WEBM_OPTS -b:v 1500k -vf scale=1280:720 -y vid-1500k.webm
```

The transcode is not yet complete, but you can see where this is headed:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff    87M Jan  4 23:27 audio.webm
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff    27M Jan  4 23:42 vid-1000k.webm
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff   285M Jan  4 23:42 vid-1500k.webm
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff    15M Jan  4 23:42 vid-500k.webm
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff    20M Jan  4 23:42 vid-700k.webm
```

The 1500k variant is disproportionately larger than the other streams.

The other problem is that when I use a shorter video, lets say eight or nine minutes, the above configuration runs as expected and everything is perfect. I don't know where the limit for this is since each test costs a lot of processing power and time, but if it's less than ten minutes, it works and if its longer than an hour, it produces massive files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the video bitrate constrained to some value it's not enough to use just `-b:v`. Depending on the source (high movement, scene complexity) the actual bitrate will go higher.

You need to specify a `-maxrate` and `-bufsize` too.

Ie. to get a variable bitrate (VBR) video constrained at around 1500k - the peak can be higher depending on the size of the VBV - you would use:

```
-b:v 1500k -maxrate 1500k -bufsize 1500k
```

For constant bitrate (CBR) the best result are achieved with a single frame VBV. Example for 25fps (1500 / 25 = 60):

```
-b:v 1500k -minrate 1500k -maxrate 1500k -bufsize 60k
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I knew this was working the second I started it, but I wanted to make sure the videos weren't malformed. I mentioned that the scripts stopped working, what I should also mentioned is that they stopped working on videos that they previously had worked on. Do you know anything that changed with ffmpeg that now requires more precision in the parameter string?

Comment: @renvel yes, it's weird that a single variant goes so high. I don't know what changed though...